# Content does not load properly on first load, but works perfectly on refresh

Tags: html

I hope you are doing well.

The webpage does not load correctly on the first load, but it works perfectly whenever I refresh the page. Also, on the first load, I get an error(Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)).

First load:

[image]

On refresh:
[image]

Main index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

     <title>Title</title>

     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="keywords" content="">
     <meta name="author" content="">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aos.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">

     <!-- MAIN CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/editor.css">

</head>
<body>

    ...

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
     <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/aos.js"></script>
     <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
     <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Sorry, if it's been already asked. I searched everywhere and I cant why that's happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try moving the `app.css` file at the bottom of the page into the <head> with the rest of the CSS.  CSS is supposed to load before JS does.

Comment: Hello, when this things happen always check your console. Most of the times url breaks in the scripts and yes like @RaymondHolguin said you should always add your css in the head before js otherwise if any script breaks then this stylesheet will never get called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common reason for that is a slow server, which takes more time to handle the request than the request default timeout. So, when you refresh, many of the assets are loaded from the cache, allowing the assets that failed to load on the first time to load properly.

Some solutions to this problem is:

- Use CDN urls rather than loading the assets from your server `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">` instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">`
- Use Lazy loading for assets that are not used immediately. More about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading).

Sometimes, the server itself is not the bottle neck, not in terms of computation I mean, but the network is! So, make sure your server's network has enough upload speed to serve your app's needs.

I can also see that you are linking a CSS file `app.css` at the end of the `body`, and I guess this is what causing the first image you posted, typically it's a good practice to load the CSS files **before** the body, and the JS files **after** it, so that the page looks it loaded faster.

Comment: Hi there, and thanks for your response. I will let you know if it works. Also, I had questions. Is there any way I can make the HTML page download the files, THEN load the page. So, in other words, make the website slower, so that it has time to download all the required data.

Comment: @user13419697 Yes, there are couple ways to do this. One way for example is to set the `display` style of the `body` to `none`, and only set it to `block` using JavaScript when the whole content of the page loads. Another way is to use a curtain screen that has a spinner for example, that loads at the beginning, and all the page loads behind it, it only disappears when the content is fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't have to be sorry for asking out any questions. No one knows it all.

To the main question, it seems you have too many scripts loading when the site is open and it times out before it could completely finish loading.

It only finishes loading after the refresh as some of the files are already loaded.

Import only CSS and js files you need and try moving some of the scripts to the bottom end of the body tag.

Use CDN URL to load the imported scripts faster

Comment: Thanks for your response!